# Visual Basic: how can I display certain values from a group of characters

Tags: vb.net

Here we are finding the eight adjacent numbers that have the highest sum and displaying that sum. We also need to have it display the eight adjacent numbers that add up to this value. I am stuck on how to display these values. My code for what I have so far is below:

```
Dim chars As Char() = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" &
"96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" &
"85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" &
"12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" &
"66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" &
"62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" &
"30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" &
"70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" &
"65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" &
"52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" &
"53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" &
"83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" &
"82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" &
"16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" &
"17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" &
"24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" &
"07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" &
"84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" &
"05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" &
"71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
 Dim index As String = 0
    Dim x = 0
    Dim values = Array.ConvertAll(chars, Function(c) CInt(c.ToString()))
    Dim maxSum = 0
    For i = 0 To values.Length - 8
        Dim sum = values(i)
        For x = i + 1 To i + 7
            sum += values(x)
            index = i
        Next
        If sum > maxSum Then
            maxSum = sum
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(index)
    Console.WriteLine(maxSum)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Comment: **vb.net** not **VBA**

Comment: You need to move `index= i` from where you have it (inside the inner loop) to after `maxSum = sum` (when you have found a new maximum sum).

Comment: I tried that and it displayed 353, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it using two different approaches.  The first is a more traditional approach, while the second utilizes LINQ:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim chunkSize As Integer = 8
    Dim source As String =
        "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" &
        "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" &
        "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" &
        "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" &
        "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" &
        "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" &
        "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" &
        "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" &
        "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" &
        "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" &
        "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" &
        "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" &
        "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" &
        "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" &
        "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" &
        "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" &
        "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" &
        "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" &
        "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" &
        "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

    Dim strChunk As String
    Dim strMaxChunk As String = ""
    Dim curSum, MaxSum As Integer
    Dim values() As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To source.Length - chunkSize
        strChunk = source.Substring(i, chunkSize)
        values = Array.ConvertAll(strChunk.ToCharArray, Function(c) CInt(c.ToString()))
        curSum = values.Sum
        If curSum > MaxSum Then
            MaxSum = curSum
            strMaxChunk = strChunk
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Traditional")
    Console.WriteLine("Max Sum = " & MaxSum & " from " & strMaxChunk)

    Dim sums = From chunk In Enumerable.Range(0, source.Length - chunkSize).Select(Function(x) source.Substring(x, chunkSize))
               Select chunk, sum = Array.ConvertAll(chunk.ToCharArray, Function(y) CInt(CStr(y))).Sum
               Order By sum Descending

    Dim linqResult = sums.First
    Console.WriteLine("Linq")
    Console.WriteLine("Max Sum = " & linqResult.sum & " from " & linqResult.chunk)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Technically the first approach also uses LINQ at the `values.Sum` line, but that could easily be replaced with a traditional loop.

Comment: I saw this yesterday but got busy. I would have taken the "Traditional" approach of Converting the SubString chunk. I put both your solutions into functions that return StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds into an array for averaging. On 100 iterations of each, the Traditional is 30% faster.